# Mootools overriding window scroll

Tags: javascript, events, scroll, mootools

I know this is a bad idea but it's what the client has asked for so....

i'm using mootools to override the window mouse wheel scroll event, so basically when the user scrolls the wheel i'm preventing the default action and then using a morph to scroll the window.

The problem is the preventDefault() on the wheel event seems to still interrupt the morph on the window scroll.  So the window starts animating to the bottom but if you use the wheel wheel this is happening it stops the morph.

Is there a way around this?  I've seen other sites which seem to get this to work.

```
window.addEvent('mousewheel', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    scroll.toBottom();
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mootools [**FX.scroll()**](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Scroll) has a option for the mousewheel actually, it says:

> **wheelStops** - (*boolean: defaults to true*) If false, the mouse wheel will not stop the transition from happening.

I made a demo with that and it worked ok. I had a first idea to use the Core Fx's method [**.isRunning()**](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Fx/Fx#Fx%3aisRunning), but that alone didn't do the work.

Actually, and a bit surprising, I got the smoothest effect using both. The isRunning() logs on the console when the wheelStops is to `false`, but logs undefined if it is `true` (default).

```
var scroll = new Fx.Scroll('theElementsID', {
    duration: 'long',
    wheelStops: false
});

window.addEvent('mousewheel', function (e) {
    var isRunning = scroll.isRunning();
    if (scroll.isRunning()) e.preventDefault();
    scroll.toBottom();

})
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/q4V6B/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  if you keep scrolling as it animates down it still jolts around for me, is there anyway to stop that do you know? Basically i'm trying to get this effect

https://jawbone.com/speakers/jambox

but when the animation happens for me, using mootools, it jolts the scroll around as its not properly preventing the event its seems

Thanks

Comment: @user3110793 what browser do you use?

Comment: Im using chrome.  The example site i gave works in chrome.  I think they are using jquery, but you would have thought mootools would still be ok.  Its almost as if the e.preventDefault() isn't properly working

I've made a small example

http://jsfiddle.net/vxs4V/

if you click your mouse wheel once it will scroll right to the bottom, but if you scroll it more than a couple clicks it'll cancel out the morph.  

Thanks

Comment: God, sorry i was doing something really dumb, i forgot to put in the wheelstops.  Thanks for all your help guys.